# How much should I charge for setting up a client web server?

Tags: untagged

I have quite the eccentric client who wants to move all his ecommerce websites (about 5-10, all PHP/MySQL) to his own web server that I'm supposed to build. He doesn't want to hear anything about VPS hosting and all the issues and expenses related to owning a server. My responsibility would be to buy all the hardware, install and configure software, etc. How much should I charge for this? I'm planning to start with two relatively moderate Dell PowerEdge C2100 servers, one for web (NGINX), one for db (MySQL).

Comment: Your requirements are not defined. How can money be assessed before the requirements are clear. Beside the money is a function of requirements + your skill level + business concerns. Since the first is not clearly, the second appears to be low (wording of the question) and the third non existent in the question due to the disdain you hold for your client. Reword your question specifically for this site or perhaps ask for help  on programmers.stackexchange.com to help in how to best build the business quote.

Comment: One MEEEE-lion dollars!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a time estimate, multiply by an uncertainty factor of 2 and your hourly rate. Multiply the result by the "pain factor" which is a function of the pain you feel when talking to eccentric clients several times a day and the probability of the client regarding every subsequent change as a rectification of defects which has to be done at no additional charge. Season with trailing zeros to taste.